# Jquery e-mail regex CS1056: Unexpected character '\' compilation error

Tags: jquery, regex, compilation

I am getting CS1056: Unexpected character '\' compilation error in the emailReg line below. Can any one help what the wrong is in here? I have also a few more regex patterns but I have got same compilation errors.

this my jquery code.

```
<script>    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#Email').focusout(function(){
                var email=$('#Email').val();
                var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
                if( !emailReg.test( email ) ) {
                    $("#epostagecerlidegil").show();
                } else {

                }
            });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please share a fiddle showing the issue? [I cannot repro](https://jsfiddle.net/td5sb292/).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, my guess is the error is coming from some tool like Visual Studio compiling the regex.

Comment: Then, `^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+[.])+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{2,4})?$` should work OK.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is your problem: `[\w-\.]`

The primary issue is you're asking for a range that either you didn't intend to or doesn't make sense.  Also, you don't need to backslash the period.  So either: `[\w\-.]` or `[\w.-]` is what I'd expect to see.

Comment: The hyphen in `[\w-.]` is treated as a literal hyphen, it is not a problem here. See [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/td5sb292/).